# Python urllib Request object - finding out whether the request is https or http on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2

The Request object has the `url` attribute and I could do a

```
request.url.startswith('https:')
```

or

```
request.url.startswith('http:')
```

to see if the request is an `https`, but I am wondering if there is a more cleaner/elegant way to do this.

I am doing this on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using webapp2, you can use request.scheme.

Comment: This seems cleaner. In the interest of completing the answer, essentially in webapp2 request.scheme == 'http' or 'https' and that is probably the best way to do this..

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation on webapps Request object on GAE, doesn't mention any property called protocol, so most likely you will need to use a trick like you mentioned, or a similar one like

```
if request.url[4] == 's'
```

which is both shorter and uglier than yours.

Comment: I agree that most likely there is nothing regarding the _protocol_ but I wouldn't go with the shorter version.. It's not very clear :) and in the end is not shorter if you need to put a comment on top of this line :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check `request.environ.get('wsgi.url_scheme') == 'https'`, but your way doesn't seem particularly unclean to me.